# Re-ordering numeric columns

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP/MySQL for a web application. Users can enter line items for different jobs. The order of the line items is important. For this I have an 'ordernumber' field. It's easy to insert new lines; I just add one to the highest current order number. But for deleting and inserting lines it becomes tricky. Right now I use a query to update all of the ordernumbers after each delete. However, sometimes there could be many deletes in the same request. I am thinking there is an easier way. For example, if the ordernumbers in the table are

```
1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10
```

Is there an update query I could run to update them to

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: this sounds like a linked list.

Comment: why you need to reorder rows after delete? ORDER BY `ordernumber` will continue to work with missing numbers.

Comment: Can you store the order number with the line instead of in a comma separated list?

Comment: Marcus - It is stored inside the record as a field. Sorry just wrote the comma list as a means to describe the issue.

Comment: Ivan - Yes I know it will still work for deletes but I need the integrity for inserts.

Comment: `select max(ordernumber)+1 as next from` ...

Comment: @dano It sounds like you're not using an auto_increament field, have you considered that? Or maybe I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a row:

```
update mytable
set ordernumber = ordernumber-1
where ordernumber > {number deleted}
```

It shouldn't matter if there are multiple deletes as this is a relative update.

Answer (score 0):

To update the entire sequence:
(this works in SQL Server - maybe you can adapt it for MySQL!)

```
while exists (
    select *
    from mytable mt1
    where not exists (
        select *
        from mytable mt2
        where mt2.ordernumber = mt1.ordernumber - 1
        )
    and mt1.ordernumber > 1
    )
begin
    update mytable
    set ordernumber = (
        select isnull( max( mt3.ordernumber ), 0) + 1
        from dbo.mytable mt3
        where mt3.ordernumber < mytable.ordernumber
    )
end
```